# SKM StyleEditor: How to hide street badges?

Tags: skmaps

How can I remove badges from the map with StyleEditor?
See screenshot (badges marked with red circles).

[image: map with street badges shown]

Answer (score 1):

The badges are textures – you can find them in the /MapResources folder of the StyleEditor.

Inside that folder they are separated on “base style” basis: DayStyle, NightStyle and Common – if you have a style specific texture that you want to use (e.g. change the highway badge only in grayscale) then put the texture in the specific folder (see */MapResources/GrayscaleStyle/highway_signs.png*).

If you want to modify the highway badge in all base styles, modify */MapResources/Common/highway_signs.png*).

To not display them at all - try a fully transparent texture.

Comment: that works so far. Is it possible to also hide the label, not only the batch? And how can I have this change take effect on Android after manipulating SKMaps.zip (without reinstall of the App)?